# How to correctly use radio button to get selected value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to get the price(value) of selected radio button and use it on JS then return it and display it on HTML

Javascript :

```
      $scope.bases = [{
      name:'Tomato',
      price:3
    },{
      name:'Cream',
      price:4
    }];
```

HTML :

```
<label for="bases">Base :</label>
      <ul name="bases">
        <li ng-repeat="base in bases">
          <input type="radio" name="bases" ng-value="{{base.prix}}" ng-model="selectedValue">{{base.nom}} {{base.prix}} €</li>
      </ul>
...
{{price}}
```

Function JS :

```
$scope.PriceBase = function()
{
      var price = 0;
      // Dunno => get price of radio button
      // Calculate on it
      price + 1.20;
      // Return it to show it on HTML
      return price;

};
```

Comment: what is "base.prix" & "base.nom" ? from where you can find the value of it?

Answer (score 6):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function($scope) {

  $scope.selected= {
    name: "Cream",
    price: 5.2
  };
  $scope.items= [{
    name: "Tomato",
    price: 3
  }, {
    name: "Cream",
    price: 4
  }];
  $scope.PriceChangeRateBase = function(priceValue) {
    $scope.selected.price= parseInt(priceValue) + 1.20;;

  };
  $scope.getItems = function() {
    return $scope.items;
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <div>Which one?</div>
    <label class="radio" ng-repeat="item in getItems()">
      <input type="radio" ng-model="selected.name" name="itemOptions" ng-change="PriceChangeRateBase(item.price)" value="{{item.name}}">{{item.name}} - ${{item.price}}
    </label>
    <hr />
    <div>You picked: {{selected.name}} - ${{selected.price}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code instead of yours

```
<label for="bases">Base :</label>
      <ul name="bases">
        <li ng-repeat="base in bases">
          <input type="radio" name="bases" ng-change="PriceBase(base.price)" ng-value="{{base.price}}" ng-model="selectedValue">{{base.name}} {{base.price}} €</li>
      </ul>
...
{{price}}
```

controller

```
$scope.PriceBase = function(valueOfrdb)
{
      $scope.price = valueOfrdb;
      // Dunno => get price of radio button
      // Calculate on it
     return parseInt(price) + 1.20;          
};
```

### EDIT

//Or try this way

```
<label for="bases">Base :</label>
          <ul name="bases">
            <li ng-repeat="base in bases">
              <input type="radio" name="bases" ng-change="PriceBase()" ng-value="{{base.price}}" ng-model="selectedValue">{{base.name}} {{base.price}} €</li>
          </ul>
    ...
    {{price}}
```

//Controller

```
    $scope.PriceBase = function(valueOfrdb)
    {
      if($scope.selectedValue!=undefined)
      {
       return parseInt($scope.selectedValue) + 1.20;          
      }
      return 0.00
    };
```

Comment: I think you should check first if the radio button is checked or not

Comment: @Kgn-web `ng-change="PriceBase(base.price)" ` this ng-change attribute fires only click on the radio button

Comment: Yes. You're right. But I am asking you to put a if condition to check if the radio button is checked

Comment: `if(selectedValue){ }`

Comment: I have pass the radio button  value on the method `PriceBase(base.price)"` via parameter. So don't need to do this. `ng-model` means two way binding of data concepts. It's not need in this situation

Answer (score -1):

```
$scope.PriceBase = function()
{
var price = 0;
var radios = document.getElementsByName('bases');

for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {

        price=radios[i].value;

        // only one radio can be logically checked, don't check the rest
        break;
    }
}
 price + 1.20;
      // Return it to show it on HTML
      return price;
});
```

Comment: Why you using loop here? If OP had 1000 of records, then your code will take lot of time to load,  whenever click the radio button.

Comment: loop is for radio buttons not for records. it will check the radio button with name basses and pick value of checked radio button only. and break willl occur when it finds a checked radio button